# "MongoError: The $changeStream stage is only supported on replica sets" error when running MongoDB in docker

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, mongoose, docker-compose

I faced an error while running `MongoDB in docker`. When I was running my docker-composer file. The `node-app-setup` container gave the following error and my HTTP server was crashed. But, my `mongo-express` container working fine. On the other hand. When I  `MongoDB atlas` the error was gone. And my app(`node-app-setup`) was running well.

How can I solve this problem?

Error message from Docker log:

```
> nodemon ./bin/www
[nodemon] 2.0.6
[nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
[nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
[nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
[nodemon] starting `node ./bin/www`
mongodb://db:27017/mydb?authSource=admin
Master 35 is running
test-app is listening on http://localhost:8089
connected mongoose

events.js:292
throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
^

MongoError: The $changeStream stage is only supported on replica sets
at MessageStream.messageHandler (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:20)
at MessageStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
at processIncomingData (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:144:12)
at MessageStream._write (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/message_stream.js:42:5)
at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:352:12)
at MessageStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:303:10)
at Socket.ondata (_stream_readable.js:719:22)
at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:309:12)
at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:223:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23)
Emitted 'error' event on ChangeStream instance at:
at ChangeStream.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongoose/lib/cursor/ChangeStream.js:41:51)
at ChangeStream.emit (events.js:315:20)
at processError (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js:571:38)
at ChangeStreamCursor.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js:435:5)
at ChangeStreamCursor.emit (events.js:315:20)
at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:343:16
at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:736:9
at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/change_stream.js:329:9
at done (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:458:7)
at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/cursor.js:533:11
at executeCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:70:5)
at callbackWithRetry (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/execute_operation.js:122:14)
at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/operations/command_v2.js:88:9
at /usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection_pool.js:348:13
at handleOperationResult (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/server.js:558:5)
at MessageStream.messageHandler (/usr/src/app/node_modules/mongodb/lib/cmap/connection.js:268:11) {
ok: 0,
code: 40573,
codeName: 'Location40573'
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My Docker Compose code:

```
version: '3.8'

networks:
  my-network-nodeApp:

services:

  db:
    container_name: mongo
    image: mongo:4.2.0
    restart: always
    ports:
     - 27017:27017
    # environment:
      # - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root
      # - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=example
    networks:
      - my-network-nodeApp

  db-mangement:
    container_name: mongo-express
    image: mongo-express
    restart: always
    depends_on:
      - db
    ports:
      - 8081:8081
    environment:
      # ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINUSERNAME: root
      # ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_ADMINPASSWORD: example
      ME_CONFIG_MONGODB_SERVER: db
    networks:
      - my-network-nodeApp


  app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./docker/node/Dockerfile.Dev
    image: "node-app"
    depends_on: 
      - db
      - db-mangement
    container_name: "node-app-setup"
    restart: always
    # command: npm start
    ports:
      - "8089:8089"
    volumes:
      - ./:/usr/src/app
      # - /app/code/node_modules
    networks:
      - my-network-nodeApp
```

My `.env` variable:

```
MONGODB_HOST=mongodb://db:27017/mydb?authSource=admin
```

*MY `app.js` DB CONNECTION CODE*

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

console.log(process.env.MONGODB_HOST);

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_HOST, {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
});
const db = mongoose.connection;
db.on("error", console.error.bind(console, "connection error:"));
db.once("open", function () {
  console.log("connected mongoose");
});
```

Comment: You do not need to add `!!! Help !!!` to the title of your question. By asking a question here it is already clear that you want help.

Comment: Thanks @mkrieger1

Comment: Run a replica set as the error message instructs.

Comment: @D.SM can you give me some resources. How can I create replica set in docker?

Comment: This is probably described in the same place where you found instructions for creating your existing deployment.